# How to disable account registration on login page?

Tags: kiwi-tcms

There was a need to disable account registration on the login page.

After small search i found an issue on github and when this option has been added:
https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/2500

I found required parameter at `/tcms/settings/common.py` and official documentation show me to change value of `REGISTRATION_ENABLED` to `False`:
https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html

I changed value and restart docker container from directory with it:

`docker-compose restart`

But account registration field still appear. Clearly, further action is required. But I can't find the answer in the official documentation and I don't have enough experience with docker. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I carefully read the documentation again, i'm realized that any customization requires remake the docker image:

https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing_docker.html#customized-docker-image

I updated repository under kiwi directory:
`git fetch`

`git checkout v11.7 //latest kiwi release at this moment`

had made necessary changes at tcms/settings/common.py

built new docker image:

`make docker-image`

and started services:

`docker-compose up -d`

Comment: An important update, please follow this documentation while kiwi customization: https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing_docker.html#customization In my case there was an permissions issues on my linux machine and this option did not work. When i solved the problem with permissions, I was able to customized kiwi tcms at local_setting.py Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by setting the environment variable during docker startup:

```
KIWI_REGISTRATION_ENABLED: false
```